# Insert New Record to the tblPurchase Table Update tblProductStockTable Quantity

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have table called tblPurchase and tblProductStock. When I insert new record to the tblPurchase table I want to update my tblProductStock table. `

```
Alter TRIGGER [dbo].[trig_passQuantity_toProductStock] 
ON [dbo].[tblPurchase]
AFTER INSERT 
AS
BEGIN  
    SELECT MAX(ItemName) ItemName,
    ItemCode,
    SUM(Quantity) Quantity  
    FROM tblPurchase
    GROUP BY itemCode;

    UPDATE tblProductStock
    SET Quantity = tblProductStock.Quantity
    FROM tblPurchase WHERE tblProductStock.ItemCode = tblPurchase.ItemCode

    INSERT INTO tblProductStock
    (
        ItemName,
        ItemCode,
        Quantity
    )
    SELECT  ItemName, ItemCode, Quantity FROM tblPurchase WHERE ItemCode NOT IN (SELECT ItemCode FROM tblProductStock)
END
```

I used above trigger to update and inset data. insert is working as expected. but Update query is not working. This is my both tables
[image]

In here I add Dell Laptop twice. But In my tblProductStock table did not change to 110. still showing 50. How can I edit this Update query.

Comment: Your `TRIGGER` is only defined as `AFTER INSERT`; of course nothing will have after an `UPDATE`, an `UPDATE` isn't an `INSERT`. Your trigger either needs to trigger on an `UPDATE` as well, or you need to create a separate one to handle `UPDATE` statements, if the logic differs.

Comment: Use SQL Server Management Studio and verify the quantity.  Need to know if data in database got changed.  It is possible the inservt worked and the view in c# did not get updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, this type of trigger would update the stock using a query on the `inserted` table.  Something like this:

```
UPDATE ps
    SET Quantity = ps.Quantity + i.quantity
    FROM tblProductStock ps JOIN
         (SELECT i.ItemCode, SUM(quantity) as quantity
          FROM inserted i
          GROUP BY i.itemCode
         ) i
         ON ps.ItemCode = i.ItemCode;
```

It is not clear exactly what else the trigger is doing, but this appear to be the question you are asking.

Comment: I think OP wants an UPSERT to `tblProductStock`

Comment: Thanks @Gordon Linoff. Its working well. Problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Triggers have special INSERTED and DELETED tables to track "before" and "after" data. So you can use something like IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM DELETED) to detect an update. You only have rows in DELETED on update, but there are always rows in INSERTED.